# How to code PowerShell script to restore a db with multiple .trn files to restore to a point in time?

Tags: powershell, t-sql

I'm attempting to restore a database that has multiple .trn files, Is there a way to list every tlog in a directory, and then use a write-host to each file with the proper tsql so it can restore i.e.

```
$Path = "S:\S_Logs"

$TSQL = "RESTORE Log FPRD FROM DISK = N'$Path\$Logs' WITH NORECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 20"

$Logs =  gci $Path -Filter "*.ldf" | Sort-object -property LastWriteT | Write-Output
```

I'm sure there is a better way, and I'm possibly going about it the worst way, but any advice will help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved for you already. Get the [`dbatools` module](https://dbatools.io) from the PowerShell Gallery and check out [Restore-DbaDatabase](https://dbatools.io/functions/restore-dbadatabase/).

```
Restore-DbaDatabase -path s:\s_logs -sqlserver YOURSERVER -RestoreTime RESTORE_POINT -DatabaseName YOURDATABASE
```